# Click an exact match in cypress from drop down

Tags: cypress

Firstly ,I was doing `cy.contains(option)` with it was clicking the exact value eg -I want to click `One` but `One One` is also there so `cy.contains` not working.

I tried Regex but it is not working

I am trying to click the exact match from drop down writing test step as ;

```js
cy.contains(new RegExp(option, "g"))
```

but not giving me correct output. I am getting error : `Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find content: 'option' but never did.`

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using a dropdown, you can and should use the `.select()` command which will choose the option by exact match:

```js
cy.get('select')
  .select('One')
  .should('have.value', 'One')
```

When the dropdown is like this, the above will choose the 2nd option.

```html
<select>
  <option>One One</option>
  <option>One</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

for the regex to work, you need to use the `^` and `$` characters to indicate beginning and end of string

```js
// works on <span>One</span> but not on <span> One </span> or <span>One One</span>
cy.get(`span`).contains(/^One$/)

// so you might want to also include white space
cy.get(`span`).contains(/^\s?One\s?$/)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can click using the dropdown option if you now by default what is the option

cy.get(DROPDOWN IDENTIFIER).eq(NUMBER OF THE DROPDOWN MATCH).click();

What do you want is the .click() function to click on the match.

This will not work if you dropdown menu is a .